# Command not found in cogs

Tags: discord.py

I was trying to make my code a little cleaner by using cogs but it doesn't seem to work. When I do +balance this error comes up: `Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "balance" is not found:` Here's the code part in main.py:

```
for file in os.listdir("./cogs"): # lists all the cog files inside the cog folder.
    if file.endswith(".py"): # It gets all the cogs that ends with a ".py".
        name = file[:-3] # It gets the name of the file removing the ".py"
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}") # This loads the cog.
```

And from the balance file:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')

class Balance(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.command(aliases = ["bal"])
async def balance(self, ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    #bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",color = (0x95a5a6), description = f"{wallet_amt} dogecoins")
    #em.add_field(name = "Bank balance",value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

async def open_account(user):
  
  users = await get_bank_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 250
    users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0


  with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
  return True

async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
      users = json.load(f)

    return users


async def update_bank(user,change = 0,mode = "wallet"):
  users = await get_bank_data()
  
  users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

  with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
  return True

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Balance(bot))
```

I'm new to coding and cogs especially so if anyone knows how to fix this, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if the commands and functions you're showing are inside the class or not. Also, why are you creating a new Bot instance, and why does your init function take an argument called `client` and then set `self.bot` to `bot`?
Try replacing `client` in your init function with `bot`, or vice versa.
Do you get any errors when you try to run your main file?